# jQuery find text in a table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I need an algorithm that calls only text in a row.

My td consists of numbers and text, I want only text in my "td".

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/3yYFY/1

For example:

***in second row*** = accure, alligator, badger

***in third row*** = Zebra, Elephant

There is a lot of rows(td) in my table and the text is not located in a specific column

HTML :

```
    <table id="docsTable">
    <tr bgcolor="#E7DDCC" class="liste-0">
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>Document Title 1</td>
        <td>567</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#E7DDCC">
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>accure</td>
        <td>134</td>
        <td>alligator</td>
        <td>badger</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#E7DDCC">
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>Zebra</td>
        <td>231</td>
        <td>Elephant</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type='button' id='btnTest' value='Get Rows' />
```

jQuery :

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnTest').click(function() {
        var arr = $('#docsTable tr').has('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
            alert($('td:eq(1)', this).text())
        });

    });
});​
```

Comment: alert($(this).text()) will return text for each row. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: i need to only all letters in a row,
for an example in second row : accure, alligator, badger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final **UPDATE**:

Use this:    http://jsfiddle.net/uJdj9/2/

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnTest').click(function() {
        var arr = $('#docsTable tr').has('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
            var text = "";
            $(this).find('td').each(function(){
                var txt = $(this).text();
                if(txt && !txt.match(/\d/g))
                  text += txt + ', ';
            })
            text = text.replace(/,([^,]*)$/,'');
            alert(text);
        });

    });
});​
```

Or like that if you know wich td to discard:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uJdj9/

```
  $(function() {
    $('#btnTest').click(function() {
        var arr = $('#docsTable tr').has('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
            var text = "";
            $('td',this).not(':eq(2)').each(function(){
                text += $(this).text()?$(this).text() +', ':'';
            })
            alert(text);
        });

  });
});​
```

Comment: thanks, can you look this demo, in the fourth line, that works not : 

http://jsfiddle.net/uJdj9/1/

i have a lot of column, and words and numbers are in different column

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$(function() {
$('#btnTest').click(function() {
    var arr = $('#docsTable tr').has('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
        alert($('td', this).text())
    });

});
```

});​

http://jsfiddle.net/3yYFY/4/

Comment: that works thanks, but i want to call only letters not numbers,

Comment: use replace function to remove the number